# Java Argument unique argument

Tags: java, object

I have been working on Java off late, couldn't figure out what this (String... arg) means in

public static void main(String... arg) {}

Comment: Should be String[] args, perhaps that's just notation for an array of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...` is called varargs and is used to allow for variable number of function parameters.

For example if you declare a function as

```
void F(int a, int... arr) { }
```

Then you can call it as:

```
F(100, 4);
```

or

```
F(100, 4, 5);
```

or

```
F(100, 4, 5, 6);
```

The variable `arr` is actually of type int[] in the body of the function and it contains the parameters, so arr = [4], arr = [4, 5] and arr = [4,5,6] respectively

Answer (score 3):

It's [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Comment: Would the answer been better if I'd copied&pasted the content of the link? :P

Answer (score 1):

They are known as [Varargs (Variable arguments)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). This allows you to send a variable number of parameters. Varargs can be used for both ojects or primitives.

eg: void setArgs(int arg1, String... args)

Some things to notice are,

The vararg must be the last parameter of a method.

There can only be one vararg parameter in a method.